# Как отследить появление слова и выполнить функцию?

Tags: javascript

Как отследить появление определённого слова и выполнить функцию. Пытался что-то сделать, но этот код не работает. Где в нем ошибка?

```
const targetElement = document.querySelector(".send");
        new MutationObserver( mutationsList, observer => {
          
          for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
          
            if (mutation.type === 'characterData' && targetElement.textContent.includes('Слово'))
            {
               myfunction();      
           }   
          } 
        }).observe(targetElement, {characterData: true, subtree: true });
        
        function myfunction() {
          alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
        }
    
    <div class="send">Слово</div>
```

Comment: Я пока сам учусь, а репутации для комментариев не хватает, поэтому прошу не минусить за ответ. А что если слушать событие через 'onchange', а потом просто проверять условие и в случае соответствия запускать функцию?

Comment: Да я тоже учусь, поэтому мне твой ответ не поможет)) Мне бы исправленный код помог)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Код рабочий, но нужно быть внимательнее с синтаксисом - если аргументов передаваемых в функцию больше, чем один, то весь набор нужно заключить в скобки:

```js
new MutationObserver( mutationsList, observer => { ... } ) // Неправильно

new MutationObserver( (mutationsList, observer) => { ... } ) // Правильно
```

```js
const targetElement = document.querySelector('.send');

new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
  for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
    if (mutation.type === 'characterData' && targetElement.textContent.includes('Слово')) {
      myfunction();
    }
  }
}).observe(targetElement, { characterData: true, subtree: true });

function myfunction() { alert('Hello! I am an alert box!!') }
```

```html
<div class="send" contenteditable>Введите здесь "слово" с заглавной буквы: </div>
```