# Как отследить смену слова в контейнере div и выполнить функцию?

Tags: javascript

На странице имеется контейнер `<div class="word">Привет</div>`  Как с помощью MutationObserver сделать так, что-бы когда в контейнере div имеется текст "Привет" выполняласть одна функция, а когда любое другое слово или текст, то вторая функция?

Comment: Всмысле? А чем не нравится этот ответ? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1548487/331312
Вы же задавали такой же вопрос и получили на него ответ. Если вы не получили нормальный ответ, вы можете написать автору в комментариях к ответу и он может подсказать вам

Comment: Михаил Камахин ответ наравится и я его принял. В этом вопросе другая задача.

Comment: Дайте своему аккаунту какое-то имя, а не дефолтное, чтобы вас можно было тегать. Изменил, всё работает, с добавлением узлов

Answer (score 2):

`onInputHello` - срабатывает, когда ввели `привет`, пробелы не учитываются
`noOnInputHello` - срабатывает, когда ввели любой другой текст

```js
const inputNode = document.querySelector('.input');
const outputNode = document.querySelector('.output');
const btnHelloNode = document.querySelector('.btn_hello');
const btnNoHelloNode = document.querySelector('.btn_no-hello');
const btnClearNode = document.querySelector('.btn_clear');
const defaultTextInput = inputNode.innerText;

function initMutationObserver(findedText, fnTrue, fnFalse) {
  new MutationObserver((mutationsList, observer) => {
    for (let mutation of mutationsList) {
      if (
        (
          mutation.type === 'characterData' ||
          mutation.type === 'childList'
        ) &&
        inputNode.textContent.trim().toLowerCase() === findedText
      ) {
        fnTrue();
      } else {
        fnFalse();
      }
    }
  }).observe(inputNode, { characterData: true, subtree: true, childList: true });
}

function onInputHello() {
  outputNode.innerText = 'Ввели привет';
}

function noOnInputHello() {
  outputNode.innerText = 'Ввели не привет';
}

function createAndAppendNodeInsertIntoInput(nodeText, nodeIntoInsert) {
  const divNode = document.createElement('div');

  divNode.innerText = nodeText;
  nodeIntoInsert.append(divNode);
}

initMutationObserver('привет', onInputHello, noOnInputHello);

btnHelloNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createAndAppendNodeInsertIntoInput('привет', inputNode);
});

btnNoHelloNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  createAndAppendNodeInsertIntoInput('не привет', inputNode);
});

btnClearNode.addEventListener('click', () => {
  inputNode.innerHTML = '';
});
```

```css
html {
  color-scheme: dark light;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  gap: 10px;
}

.input {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 8px;
}

.output {
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 4px dashed orange;
}

[contenteditable] {
  border: 2px solid currentColor;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  transition: border-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

[contenteditable]:focus {
  border-color: #4e4efb;
}
```

```html
<div class="input" contenteditable>
  Сюда вводить привет
</div>

<div class="output">
  Ввели привет или не привет
</div>

<button class="btn btn_hello" type="button">
  Добавил узел "<span>привет</span>"
</button>

<button class="btn btn_no-hello" type="button">
  Добавил узел "<span>не привет</span>"
</button>

<button class="btn btn_clear" type="button">
  Очистить
</button>
```

Comment: Михаил, спасибо, вижу код работает. Но как оказалось у меня не меняется слово в контейнере, а появляется новый div с новым словом, поэтому код у меня и не работает. Нужно получается отследить  появление этого div c новым словом. Можно как-то добавить/убрать в вашем коде, что бы получилось то, что мне надо?

Comment: Михаил, не могу понять почему этот код не работает на сайте редакторе кода codepen.io. Но когда меняешь `observe(inputNode, { characterData: true, subtree: true, childList: true });`  на `observe(document.querySelector('body'), {characterData: true, subtree: true, childList: true });` Начинает работать. Почему так? Почему не работает с inputNode? Можно как-то это решить?

Comment: @Иван body нельзя ставить, происходит поиск по всему дереву, оно очень большое, это будет работать очень медленно

Comment: @Иван без понятия, почему у вас не работает, вы что-то не так делаете, всё работает
https://codepen.io/mihinov/pen/MWLywqz
Я вставил код с помощью CTRL+C / CTRL+V

Comment: Михаил, я не весь код копирую, а только ту часть которая мне нужна. Копирую ту часть, которая должна выполнять нужную мне задачу. https://codepen.io/joldeepf-the-vuer/pen/Rwvarym  в поле HTML     меняю слово. Сейчас код работает, но стоит поменять на inputNode сразу тишина.

Comment: @Иван выражение - поменять на inputNode - непонятно. Я советую вам изучить работу с DOM. Вставка узлов, создание узлов, редактирование узлов, удаление узлов, поиск в узле, поиск в узлах
https://learn.javascript.ru/dom-nodes

Comment: @Иван данный код ищет отслеживает изменения в узле inputNode, который находится по селектору `.input`. Селектор можно написать любой. Если у вас на сайте много разных кусков кода, то вам нужно в переменную inputNode получить узел, в котором планируется изменение текста

Comment: Михаил, выражение - поменять на inputNode это если сделать как у вас в коде `observe(inputNode, { characterData: true, subtree: true, childList: true });` Ту ссылку которую я вам дал на Codepen там у меня написано так ` observe(document.querySelector('body'), { characterData: true, subtree: true, childList: true });`  и код работает, а если поменять как написано у вас  `observe(inputNode, { characterData: true, subtree: true, childList: true });` то код перестаёт работать. Хотелось бы понять почему.  Почему  с селектором body работает, а селектор `querySelector('.input');` не находит что-ли?

Comment: @Иван я сказал, нужно прочитать про DOM!!! Почему не находит - наверное, потому что элемента с классом .input в браузере нету?